# Get first key of nested object with react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, axios

I'm really new in react and i am trying axios to get some data and then with a post request update them. This is my object

```
{
"id": "text",
"users": {
    "George": {
        "age": "6"
    }
}}
```

In my code i am trying to get "George" age like this:

```
const [subparameters, setSubParameters] = React.useState(null);
const params = [];
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(r.data.users.George)){
        const _parm = {parKey: key, parValue: value };
        console.log(_parm);
        params.push(_parm);
        setSubParameters(params)
      }
```

But in my POST request "George" changes and `r.data.parameters.George` doesn't work anymore because instead of this name is another one. any ideas of solving this somehow?

Comment: You can use r.data.users[Object.keys(r.data.users)[0]].

Comment: Do upvote, if it helps :)

Comment: @FarrukhRashid  this  r.data.users[Object.keys(r.data.users)[0]] only returns George but if my JSON is like this after post request: 
"users": {
    "George": {
        "age": "6"
    },
 "Maria": {
        "age": "7"
    },
 "Amy": {
        "age": "8"
    }
}
how do i get each different name object key value? Because i want to compare it with another variable.

Comment: The Object.keys(r.data.users) returns an array of all the names, i.e ["george", "maria"].
You can map through it and compare.

Comment: @FarrukhRashid you are right! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapping over `r.data.users.George`, map over `r.data.users`:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(r.data.users)){
        const _parm = {parKey: key, parValue: value }; // key = Geroge, value = {age: 6}
        console.log(_parm);
        params.push(_parm);
        setSubParameters(params)
      }
```

Comment: actually the value of the mapping you suggeted is value ={"age": "6"}

Comment: Yep, you are correct. Do you want to get `key=age` , `value=6` or `key=George`, `value=6`?