# How to get the key inside a nested object in react

Tags: reactjs

I have this data in a json file that I need to use in reactjs:

```
{
  "t": {
    "randomdocid67233": {
      "name": "ABC",
      "latinName": "DEF"
    },
    "randomdocid67234": {
      "name": "GHI",
      "latinName": "JKI"
    }
  }
}
```

I can get the "t" using `Object.keys(data)`, the "randomdocid67233" using the `Object.keys(data[Object.keys(data)[0]])`, and the "ABC" using `data.t.randomdocid67233[Object.keys(data.t.randomdocid67233)[0]]`.

But what I want to get is the keys, "name", and "latinName" and store it in an array like this `const someVal = ["name", "latinName"]`.

Is there any way to achieve this? I have spent hours trying to find solution to this like what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69538656/get-first-key-of-nested-object-with-react) but the output when I tried it is the values ["ABC", "DEF"].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it do be dynamic

```js
const data = {
    "t": {
        "randomdocid67233": {
            "name": "ABC",
            "latinName": "DEF"
        },
        "randomdocid67234": {
            "name": "GHI",
            "latinName": "JKI"
        }
    }
}


const firstObject = data.t[Object.keys(data.t)[0]]
console.log(Object.keys(firstObject))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
Object.keys(data.t.randomdocid67233)
```